# PHPMailer SMTP ERROR: Password command failed

Tags: php, phpmailer

I am trying to send feedback to mail id from web site but I am getting this error:

> 2017-12-03 12:03:48   Could not access file: /var/tmp/file.tar.gz 2017-12-03 12:03:48 Could not access file: /tmp/image.jpg 2017-12-03 12:03:48   SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP p42sm12855091wrb.28 - gsmtp 2017-12-03 12:03:48  CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO www.shreephotovision.ml 2017-12-03 12:03:48  SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [185.27.134.45] 250-SIZE 35882577 250-8BITMIME 250-STARTTLS 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES 250-PIPELINING 250-CHUNKING 250 SMTPUTF8 2017-12-03 12:03:48  CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS 2017-12-03 12:03:48  SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS 2017-12-03 12:03:48  CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO www.shreephotovision.ml 2017-12-03 12:03:48  SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [185.27.134.45] 250-SIZE 35882577 250-8BITMIME 250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES 250-PIPELINING 250-CHUNKING 250 SMTPUTF8 2017-12-03 12:03:48 CLIENT -> SERVER: AUTH LOGIN 2017-12-03 12:03:48    SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 VXNlcm5hbWU6 2017-12-03 12:03:48  CLIENT -> SERVER: bWlsaW5kYmh1dmFkMTk4OEBnbWFpbC5jb20= 2017-12-03 12:03:48  SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6 2017-12-03 12:03:48 CLIENT -> SERVER: bW5iQDI4MDc= 2017-12-03 12:03:49   SERVER -> CLIENT: 534-5.7.14 Please log in via your web browser and 534-5.7.14 then try again. 534-5.7.14 Learn more at 534 5.7.14 https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 p42sm12855091wrb.28 - gsmtp 2017-12-03 12:03:49 SMTP ERROR: Password command failed: 534-5.7.14 Please log in via your web browser and 534-5.7.14 then try again. 534-5.7.14 Learn more at 534 5.7.14 https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 p42sm12855091wrb.28 - gsmtp 2017-12-03 12:03:49  SMTP Error: Could not authenticate. 2017-12-03 12:03:49 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT 2017-12-03 12:03:49  SERVER -> CLIENT: 221 2.0.0 closing connection p42sm12855091wrb.28 - gsmtp 2017-12-03 12:03:49  SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting Message could not be sent.Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

Here is my code:

```
<?php
$name = $_REQUEST['name'] ;
$mobile = $_REQUEST['mobile'] ;
$email = $_REQUEST['email'] ;
$message = $_REQUEST['message'] ;

require 'phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;                               // Enable verbose debug output
$mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';                 // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'milindbhuvad1988@gmail.com';                 // SMTP username
$mail->Password = '********';                           // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
$mail->Port = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to
$mail->setFrom('milindbhuvad1988@gmail.com', '');
$mail->addAddress('milindbhuvad1988@gmail.com', '');     // Add a recipient
$mail->addAddress('milindbhuvad1988@gmail.com');               // Name is optional
$mail->addReplyTo('info@example.com', 'Information');
$mail->addCC('cc@example.com');
$mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');
$mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         // Add attachments
$mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    // Optional name
$mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = 'You have received feedback from your website!';
$mail->Body    = "
<strong>Name:</strong> $name <hr>
<strong>Name:</strong> $mobile <hr>
<strong>Email:</strong> $email <hr>
<strong>Message:</strong> $message <hr>";

$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

if(!$mail->send()) {    
echo 'Message could not be sent.';    
echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {   
?>
<script type="text/javascript">         
alert('Thanks Your Feedback');          
window.location.href='index.html';  
</script>';
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Given the error `Password command failed` and `Could not authenticate`, what would your own guess be?

Comment: Similarly, what do you think `Could not access file: /var/tmp/file.tar.gz` might mean?

Comment: there a actually 2 errors. your file can't be attached and you missing your GMail-oAuth Credentials.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `$mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz'); 
$mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');`
or link to an actual attachment you want to send. Also updating the certificates in the `php.ini` worked for me.